# jQuery how to read this JSON string from responseText

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have tried almost everyway here on stack overflow, but somehow I cannot read JSON string data returned from a success function call in jquery ajax. my success function receives following JSON string:

```
Object {
  readyState = 4, responseText = "{"
  Response ":200,"
  Data ":"
  6 ","
  Message ":"
  6 "}", status = 200, statusText: "OK"
}
```

This is my success callback:

```
success: function(response, msg, responseText) {
   if (response.Response == 200) {
     console.log("Data was submitted");
     var obj = responseText;

     console.log(typeof obj);
   } else if (response.Response == 400) {
     console.log("there was some error");
   }
 }
```

When success function is fired and checks for status code, it executes                  console.log("Data was submitted"); statement successfully, however, I am not able to access the "Data":"6" key/value pair.

So far I have tried doing this:

```
var obj = responseText;
console.log(obj.Data);
```

and

```
console.log(obj.data[1]);
```

and numerous other ways, but either it says "undefined" or gives and error. However, when I console.log(obj), in console it shows 'obj'. which means I am getting a JSON object.

Please note that I have also tried:

```
obj = jQuery.parseJSON(responseText);
```

which gives me an error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

What to do in this situation? I want to be able to extract the value of a key name "Data": and and assign its value ="6" to a variable.

Comment: `response.Response`, `response.Data` and `response.Message`

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for your response. I tried doing this as you suggested: 
obj = responseText;
console.log(obj.Data);
However, it suggests: undefined

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan Oh Oh Oh! IT WORKED. Thank you man. Such a simple mistake.
Please post it as an answer. So that I can mark it.

Comment: response.Response is returning the correct value. In the JSON object you provided Response and Data are part of the same object... Have you tried response.Data instead of responseText.Data

Comment: @Zafar Darin got the same answer. The issue is that you're accessing the wrong parameter of the `success` handler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter of the success callback is what you need, not the third. The first parameter will represent the body of the response as returned from the server. Also you don't need to be checking for anything different than 200 status code in a success callback. That's what the `error` callback is designed for because the success callback will never be fired if your server returns 400 status code.

So:

```
dataType: 'json',
success: function (response) {
    console.log("Data was submitted");
    console.log(response.Data);
},
error: function() {
    console.log("there was some error");
}
```

Comment: @oxfn Where does it say they're deprecated? In the docs for $.ajax there's no mention under either param: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you. It worked. It worked. Rory was the first to mention it. If he posts it as an answer, I'll mark it as an answer. However, @Darin, you are right. Same as Rory. Thank you boys. Such a simple thing. I am ashamed :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry, documentation mentions only chained calls like `$.ajax({}).success().error()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ Parameters are OK

Comment: @Zafar I think you should mark Darin's answer as accepted. He solved the issue, explained it and improved your code structure too.

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan I have marked it as answer already. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The success callback is [`success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR )`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

So the 1st, `data` will contain the data returned to the `success` function.